# Get the max number without using the worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel, max

My teacher wants me to make a function or subroutine that returns the max value of a list in Excel. The list is only one column with different values and names on the left side of it. Then when my function returns the max value, it has to give you the name on the left side of that value.

How can I do this without using `worksheet.functions.max`?

Comment: SO is not a code for me or do my homework site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a "do my homework for me" site and the OP seems to not have made an attempt to find a solution to the problem before asking on SO.

Comment: For homework problems, SO prefers to give nudges in the right direction rather than posting whole solutions. Show what you've done so far and we can help you with a specific problem you're having. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18251/274986.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** through **B20**, in **C1** enter:

```
=B1
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2>C1,B2,C1)
```

and copy down.  Then in **D20** enter:

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(C20,C1:C20,0))
```

Here is an example:

[image]